# How get the serial port name of an Arduino

Tags: c#, arduino, libusb-1.0, libusbdotnet

I'm trying to figure out which serial port belongs to an `Arduino`.
Since the `SerialPort` class does not reveal any information about
the underlying hardware, I'm trying to use [LibUsbDotNet](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Using the following code to get a list of all devices:

```
UsbDevice.ForceLibUsbWinBack = true;
var devices = UsbDevice.AllDevices;
```

I can then either iterate over all of them or search for the `Arduino` specifically:

```
var deviceFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(0x2341, 0x8036);
var arduino = devices.Find(deviceFinder);
```

This actually works and I get an instance of `UsbRegistry`,
but I'm unable to open the device or determine through which serial port it is exposed.

```
USBDevice arduinoUsbDevice;
usbRegistry.Open(out arduinoUsbDevice);
```

Since this doesn't work `arduinoUsbDevice` remains `null`.

I then tried using the `DeviceNotifier` class which raises an event whenever
a device is added or removed from the system:

```
var notifier = DeviceNotifier.OpenDeviceNotifier();

notifier.OnDeviceNotify += (s, e) =>
{
    WriteLine(e.Device?.Name ?? "no device");
    WriteLine(e.Device?.IdProduct ?? 0);
    WriteLine(e.Device?.IdVendor ?? 0);
    WriteLine(e.EventType);
    WriteLine(e.Object);
    WriteLine(e.Port?.Name ?? "");
};
```

Now whenever I connect the `Arduino` to the computer, the event is raised twice.
As if two separate devices are being connected,
but only one of them is ever returned by `UsbDevice.AllDevices`:

```
` \\?\USB#VID_2341&PID_8036#7&533912d&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
32822
9025
DeviceArrival
FullName:USB#VID_2341&PID_8036#7&533912d&0&2#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
Vid:0x2341
Pid:0x8036
SerialNumber:7&533912d&0&2
ClassGuid:a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed


no device
0
0
DeviceArrival
[Port Name:COM5] 
COM5
```

The first time the event is raised for the device we could find before as well.
The second time it is raised with `e.Device` set to `null` but
with `e.Port` set to `COM5`, which is the information I'm after.

So the problem is I can only get this information when the `Arduino` is connected
after the software has been started and even then linking the two events is
kind of a guessing game.

Is there any way of getting the information without having to rely
on the events raised by the `DeviceNotifier` class?

*I'm aware I could use `System.Management` and `WMI` queries,   but
these are not available on Linux and MacOS, which is why I'm using
`LibUsbDotNet` instead.*

*The native library I'm using is [libusb-1.0](http://libusb.info/)*

Comment: "Since the SerialPort class does not reveal any information about
the underlying hardware."
If you're referring to `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` it most certainly can get the port names: `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` returns an array of strings of all the port names.